# The Messiah's hair will be greenish?

Tags: sources-mekorot, talmud-gemara, agada-stories-legends

I *think* I saw somewhere in the Gemara (almost certain it was in a commentary, not the text itself) that the Messiah's hair will be ירקרקת (green/greenish/blonde)? Unfortunately, I cannot seem to remember the place nor locate it as of yet.

Anyone know where this is stated?

Comment: Hm, never heard of this. Could this be an idea stemmed from the fact that Dovid HaMelech had red hair (I Samuel 16:12)?

Comment: Are you sure it used the word ירקרקת ? That word is used in 2 very specific situations (metzora and Esther), and then, in other writings, refers to colors of flame (and a particular angel, composed of green flame).

Comment: @rosends Yes, I remember seeing it and thinking of Esther. Note it might be a variation (i.e רקרק, or simply Yarok itself)

Comment: Probably comes from Tikkune Zohar's description of David's hair ([123b-124a](https://he.m.wikisource.org/wiki/תיקוני_זהר_קכד_א)).

Comment: @Oliver I'm thinking you're right since I'm almost certain it was in a commentary I read it

Comment: @Fei23 Then glad to have helped.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The Tikkune Zohar ([123b-124a](https://he.m.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%AA%D7%99%D7%A7%D7%95%D7%A0%D7%99_%D7%96%D7%94%D7%A8_%D7%A7%D7%9B%D7%93_%D7%90)) reads:

> דָּוִד שִׁבְעָה מִינֵי דַהֲבָא הֲוָה בְּשַׂעֲרוֹי, זָהָב יְרַקְרַק, זָהָב אוֹפָז, זָהָב אוֹפִיר, זָהָב פַּרְוָיִם, זָהָב סָגוּר, זָהָב תַּרְשִׁישׁ, זָהָב כְּלִיל כָּל גּוּוָנִים, וְאִיהוּ זְהַב שְׁבָא, וְהַאי אִיהוּ זָהָב מְזוּקָק שִׁבְעָתַיִם, וְהָכִי אִינוּן שִׁבְעָה מִינֵי חִוְורוּ, וְשֶׁבַע מִינֵי סוּמְקוּ

On this passage, R. Reuven Margolios noted in his glosses 'Nitzotze Ohr' on the TZ (p. 246 note 14), that a certain "לקוטי כת״י הגר״א" references the Zohar (Ex. 73b) that depicts the Messiah's appearance as such.

Comment: accepting this, as it definitely answers the question, but other answers are welcome